# Python: Getting difference between two lists with identical values

Tags: python, list, difference

If I have two lists i.e:

```
list1=['E', 'I', 'N', 'A', 'O', 'N', 'R']

list2=['I', 'A', 'N', 'R']
```

What algorithm can be used so that the difference between them is:

```
difference=['E' , 'O' , 'N']
```

Currently I can only get `['E' , 'O']`, which completely ignores the second 'N' in list1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter()`

```
from typing import Counter

list1 = ['E', 'I', 'N', 'A', 'O', 'N', 'R']

list2 = ['I', 'A', 'N', 'R']

c1 = Counter(list1)
c2 = Counter(list2)
c2.subtract(c1)

dif = [k for k, v in c2.items() if v != 0 for _ in range(abs(v)) ]

print(dif)
# -> ['N', 'E', 'O']
```